# How much time does it take to withdraw from Optimistic Rollup?

Tags: blockchain, rollups

I am reading [An Incomplete Guide to Rollups](https://vitalik.ca/general/2021/01/05/rollup.html) and Vitalik says the withdraw time of Optimistic Rollup takes

> ~1 week (withdrawals need to be delayed to give time for someone to
> publish a fraud proof and cancel the withdrawal if it is fraudulent)

My questions:

1. I assume withdraw means any withdraws between eth addresses. Correct? Any exceptions? If I want to withdraw from an app deployed on the l2 and deposit to uniswap(on the l2), does it take 1 week?
2. What about deposits? I assume they are the same as withdraw. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Talking about the optimistic rollup protocol in development and action [Optimism.io](https://www.optimism.io/),we can discuss 3 scenarios:

1. The transactions happening solely on L2 layer like swapping of
   tokens on L2 using Uniswap(it now also supports optimism rollup
   layer) the trasaction will be completed in seconds and at a
   comparitively very low fee than L1. Note that these transactions took place on L2 and had no interaction with L1 while executing.
2. The transaction involving moving of assets(tokens) from L1 to L2 will take few minutes and have higher fees since we are interacting with L1 compared to scenario 1.
3. The transaction involving moving of assets from L2 to L1 if done
   through the Optimism gateway(native bridge) will require to wait for
   at least 7 days for you to be able to claim them over the L1, but
   you can also choose a 3rd party bridge like Hop Exchange or Celer
   Bridge which are comparitively faster and cheaper on their transaction page.

*Source:* [Optimism Docs](https://community.optimism.io/docs/users/withdrawal.html)